# PCIE DriverKit cannot be loaded correctly due to entitlements issues

Tags: macos, iokit, pci-e, entitlements, driverkit

## My question

I already have the correct entitlements, provisioning profile and development certification, and I have turned off SIP, turned on systemextensions developer on, but it still shows
provider entitlements check failed.

### Similar problem

[PCIDriverKit Entitlement check failed (migrate KEXT to DEXT)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68242561/pcidriverkit-entitlement-check-failed-migrate-kext-to-dext)

After installing dext correctly, it is found that it cannot be started normally, and the following error is reported.

```
$ sudo dmesg | grep SmiPcie                                                                        
[  389.798271]: Driver com.wuhanjingce.driverkit.SmiPcie has crashed 0 time(s)
[  389.798283]: DK: SmiPcie-0x100000d56 waiting for server com.wuhanjingce.driverkit.SmiPcie-100000d56
[  389.861199]: Sandbox apply: taskgated-helper[1409] <bytes>Sandbox: taskgated-helper(1409) deny(1) mach-lookup com.apple.CoreServices.coreservicesdSandbox: taskgated-helper(1409) deny(1) mach-lookup com.apple.DiskArbitration.diskarbitrationd7 duplicate reports for Sandbox: taskgated-helper(1409) deny(1) mach-lookup com.apple.DiskArbitration.diskarbitrationdSandbox: taskgated-helper(1409) deny(1) file-read-metadata /Volumes/IKapC3 duplicate reports for Sandbox: taskgated-helper(1409) deny(1) file-read-metadata /Volumes/IKapCSandbox: taskgated-helper(1409) deny(1) mach-lookup com.apple.DiskArbitration.diskarbitrationdSandbox: taskgated-helper(1409) deny(1) user-preference-read kCFPreferencesAnyApplication/Library/SystemExtensions/C1281214-E917-4687-83D0-DA9A41D8E4FD/com.wuhanjingce.driverkit.SmiPcie.dext/com.wuhanjingce.driverkit.SmiPcie[1408] ==> com.apple.dextDK: com.wuhanjingce.driverkit.SmiPci[1408] has team identifier 5X63ZZ6MH3
[  389.898111]: DK: SmiPcie-0x100000d56: provider entitlements check failed
[  389.898120]: DK: IOUserServer(com.wuhanjingce.driverkit.SmiPcie-0x100000d56)::exit(Entitlements check failed)
```

And after setting according to the method provided in the introduction, the device can be opened normally.

```
sudo nvram boot-args="dk=0x8001"
```

**But my dext needs to be published correctly，Referring to the answer below, I confirmed some of my settings.**

[image]

- Sign with Apple Development.

  - dext
    [image]
  - installer app
    [image]
- Entitlements.

  The entitlements file can only automatically generate a small part, and the entitlements related to applying for pci cannot be automatically added to the entitlements file.

  Do I need to copy all the entitlements in the profile to the entitlements file? I copied part of the value here.

  - dext

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE plist PUBLIC "-//Apple//DTD PLIST 1.0//EN" "http://www.apple.com/DTDs/PropertyList-1.0.dtd">
<plist version="1.0">
<dict>
    <key>com.apple.developer.driverkit</key>
    <true/>
    <key>com.apple.developer.driverkit.allow-any-userclient-access</key>
    <true/>
    <key>com.apple.developer.driverkit.transport.pci</key>
    <array>
        <dict>
            <key>IOPCIPrimaryMatch</key>
            <string>0x000010EE&amp;0x0000FFFF</string>
        </dict>
    </array>
    <key>com.apple.developer.system-extension.redistributable</key>
    <true/>
</dict>
</plist>
```

- installer

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE plist PUBLIC "-//Apple//DTD PLIST 1.0//EN" "http://www.apple.com/DTDs/PropertyList-1.0.dtd">
<plist version="1.0">
<dict>
    <key>com.apple.developer.system-extension.install</key>
    <true/>
    <key>com.apple.security.app-sandbox</key>
    <true/>
    <key>com.apple.security.files.user-selected.read-only</key>
    <true/>
</dict>
</plist>
```

- Provision profile (entitlements part)

  - dext

```
<key>Entitlements</key>
    <dict>
        <key>com.apple.developer.driverkit</key>
        <true/>

        <key>application-identifier</key>
        <string>5X63ZZ6MH3.com.wuhanjingce.driverkit.SmiPcie</string>
        
        <key>com.apple.application-identifier</key>
        <string>5X63ZZ6MH3.com.wuhanjingce.driverkit.SmiPcie</string>

        <key>com.apple.developer.system-extension.redistributable</key>
        <true/>
                
        <key>keychain-access-groups</key>
        <array>
                <string>5X63ZZ6MH3.*</string>
        </array>
                
        <key>get-task-allow</key>
        <true/>
                
        <key>com.apple.developer.team-identifier</key>
        <string>5X63ZZ6MH3</string>
                
        <key>com.apple.developer.driverkit.allow-any-userclient-access</key>
        <true/>
                
        <key>com.apple.developer.driverkit.transport.pci</key>
        <array>
                <dict>
                <key>IOPCIPrimaryMatch</key>
                <string>0x000010EE&amp;0x0000FFFF</string>
                </dict>
        </array>
                
        <key>com.apple.security.get-task-allow</key>
        <true/>
    </dict>
```

- installer

```
<key>Entitlements</key>
    <dict>      
        <key>com.apple.developer.system-extension.install</key>
        <true/>
                
        <key>com.apple.developer.driverkit.allow-any-userclient-access</key>
        <true/>
                
        <key>com.apple.developer.driverkit</key>
        <true/>
                
        <key>com.apple.application-identifier</key>
        <string>5X63ZZ6MH3.com.wuhanjingce.driverkit.SmiInstall</string>
                
        <key>com.apple.developer.system-extension.redistributable</key>
        <true/>
                
        <key>keychain-access-groups</key>
        <array>
                <string>5X63ZZ6MH3.*</string>
        </array>
                
        <key>com.apple.developer.team-identifier</key>
        <string>5X63ZZ6MH3</string>
    </dict>
```

I think this problem should have nothing to do with the dext installer, the problem lies in my dext itself.

**I want to know, what exactly is the problem that causes the error `provider entitlements check failed`**

According to [PCIDriverKit Entitlement check failed (migrate KEXT to DEXT)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68242561/pcidriverkit-entitlement-check-failed-migrate-kext-to-dext)
tested and verified

### Add some information needed by @pmdj

- ioreg -w0 -irc IOPCIDevice

```
+-o pcic1-bridge@0  <class IORegistryEntry:IOService:IOPCIDevice, id 0x10000060c, registered, matched, active, busy 0 (314 ms), retain 14>
  | {
  |   "IOPCIExpressLinkCapabilities" = 7551233
  |   "vendor-id" = <6b100000>
  |   "class-code" = <00040600>
  |   "#msi-vectors" = <20000000>
  |   "pci-ignore-linkstatus" = <>
  |   "#size-cells" = <02000000>
  |   "IOName" = "pci-bridge"
  |   "function-dart_force_active" = <5300000074636146>
  |   "device-protection-granularity" = <d8120f4000010000>
  |   "msi-for-bridges" = <>
  |   "function-dart_self" = <53000000666c6553>
  |   "IOPCIHPType" = 49
  |   "pcidebug" = "0:0:0(1:128)"
  |   "Thunderbolt Path" = "IOService:/AppleARMPE/arm-io@10F00000/AppleT811xIO/acio1@1F00000/AppleThunderboltHALType5/AppleThunderboltNHIType5/IOThunderboltControllerType5/IOThunderboltPort@7/IOThunderboltSwitchType5/IOThunderboltPort@3"
  |   "IOPCIExpressLinkStatus" = 4113
  |   "pci-aspm-default" = 2
  |   "IOPCIExpressCapabilities" = 66
  |   "IOServiceDEXTEntitlements" = (("com.apple.developer.driverkit.transport.pci","com.apple.developer.driverkit.transport.pci.bridge"))
  |   "IOPCIConfigured" = Yes
  |   "IOInterruptControllers" = ("APCIECMSIController-apciec1")
  |   "IODTPersist" = 0
  |   "Thunderbolt Entry ID" = 4294968839
  |   "IOPCIResourced" = Yes
  |   "AAPL,slot-name" = <536c6f742d310000>
  |   "function-dart_release_sid" = <530000006c655253>
  |   "AAPL,phandle" = <52000000>
  |   "ranges" = <0000008200001000000000000000008200001000000000000000f03f00000000000000c20000004000000000000000c2000000400000000000000040000000000000008100000000000000000000008100000000000000000000000000000000>
  |   "name" = <"pcic1-bridge">
  |   "IOPowerManagement" = {"ChildrenPowerState"=2,"CurrentPowerState"=2,"CapabilityFlags"=258,"ChildProxyPowerState"=2,"MaxPowerState"=3}
  |   "default-apcie-options" = <01001080>
  |   "IOPCITunnelLinkChange" = <>
  |   "compatible" = <"pciec-bridge">
  |   "marvel-wa-viddids" = <4b1b20914b1b23914b1b28914b1b30914b1b72914b1b7a914b1b82914b1ba0914b1b20924b1b3092281c22017b1992230311450603114206340030084b1b35924b1b7191>
  |   "PCI-Thunderbolt" = <>
  |   "AppleEmbeddedPCIEPort" = "AppleT8103PCIeCPort is not serializable"
  |   "IOReportLegendPublic" = Yes
  |   "function-dart_request_sid" = <5300000071655253>
  |   "msi-vector-base" = <00000000>
  |   "IOPCIDeviceDeviceTreeEntry" = "IOService is not serializable"
  |   "reg" = <0000000000000000000000000000000000000000>
  |   "IOPCIOnline" = Yes
  |   "IOReportLegend" = ({"IOReportGroupName"="Interrupt Statistics (by index)","IOReportChannels"=((5291294645182005248,4295098369,"               First Level Interrupt Handler Count"),(5291294645182005249,4295098369,"              Second Level Interrupt Handler Count"),(5291294645182005250,4295098369,"        First Level Interrupt Handler Time (MATUs)"),(5291294645182005251,4295098369,"   Second Level Interrupt Handler CPU Time (MATUs)"),(5291294645182005252,4295098369,"Second Level Interrupt Handler System Time (MATUs)")),"IOReportChannelInfo"={"IOReportChannelUnit"=0},"IOReportSubGroupName"="pcic1-bridge 0"})
  |   "device-id" = <12100000>
  |   "#address-cells" = <03000000>
  |   "revision-id" = <00000000>
  |   "IOInterruptSpecifiers" = (<3104000000000100>)
  |   "IOPCIMSIMode" = Yes
  | }
  | 
  +-o IOPP  <class IORegistryEntry:IOService:IOPCIBridge:IOPCI2PCIBridge:ApplePCIECHostBridge, id 0x10000061c, registered, matched, active, busy 0 (310 ms), retain 10>
    +-o pci-bridge@0  <class IORegistryEntry:IOService:IOPCIDevice, id 0x10000232f, registered, matched, active, busy 0 (47 ms), retain 15>
      | {
      |   "#address-cells" = <03000000>
      |   "class-code" = <00040600>
      |   "Tunnel Endpoint GUID" = <001580f023f34300>
      |   "IOPowerManagement" = {"ChildrenPowerState"=2,"CurrentPowerState"=2,"CapabilityFlags"=258,"ChildProxyPowerState"=2,"MaxPowerState"=3}
      |   "pci-aspm-default" = 3
      |   "IOPCIHPType" = 48
      |   "vendor-id" = <86800000>
      |   "name" = <"pci-bridge">
      |   "device-id" = <78150000>
      |   "IOChildIndex" = 1
      |   "IOPCIResourced" = Yes
      |   "IODTPersist" = 0
      |   "compatible" = <"pci8086,1578","pciclass,060400">
      |   "ranges" = <0000008200000004000000000000008200000004000000000000100400000000000000c20000004000000000000000c2000000400000000000000040000000000000008100000000000000000000008100000000000000000010000000000000>
      |   "IOPCIExpressLinkCapabilities" = 4545601
      |   "IOServiceDEXTEntitlements" = (("com.apple.developer.driverkit.transport.pci","com.apple.developer.driverkit.transport.pci.bridge"))
      |   "Thunderbolt Path" = "IOService:/AppleARMPE/arm-io@10F00000/AppleT811xIO/acio1@1F00000/AppleThunderboltHALType5/AppleThunderboltNHIType5/IOThunderboltControllerType5/IOThunderboltPort@7/IOThunderboltSwitchType5/IOThunderboltPort@1/IOThunderboltPort@1/IOThunderboltSwitchType3/IOThunderboltPort@6"
      |   "IOPCIConfigured" = Yes
      |   "Thunderbolt Entry ID" = 4294976280
      |   "Tunnel Endpoint Device Model ID" = <61660000>
      |   "Tunnel Endpoint Device Vendor ID" = <43000000>
      |   "revision-id" = <00000000>
      |   "IOPCIExpressLinkStatus" = 4161
      |   "IOPCIExpressCapabilities" = 82
      |   "pcidebug" = "1:0:0(2:128)"
      |   "IOName" = "pci-bridge"
      |   "#size-cells" = <02000000>
      |   "reg" = <0000010000000000000000000000000000000000>
      |   "IOPCITunnelL1Enable" = No
      | }
      | 
      +-o IOPP  <class IORegistryEntry:IOService:IOPCIBridge:IOPCI2PCIBridge, id 0x100002334, registered, matched, active, busy 0 (33 ms), retain 12>
        +-o pci-bridge@1  <class IORegistryEntry:IOService:IOPCIDevice, id 0x100002330, registered, matched, active, busy 0 (33 ms), retain 13>
        | | {
        | |   "#address-cells" = <03000000>
        | |   "class-code" = <00040600>
        | |   "IOPCITunnelled" = Yes
        | |   "IOPCIExpressSlotStatus" = 328
        | |   "IOPowerManagement" = {"ChildrenPowerState"=2,"CurrentPowerState"=2,"CapabilityFlags"=258,"ChildProxyPowerState"=2,"MaxPowerState"=3}
        | |   "pci-aspm-default" = 3
        | |   "IOPCIHPType" = 48
        | |   "vendor-id" = <86800000>
        | |   "name" = <"pci-bridge">
        | |   "device-id" = <78150000>
        | |   "IOChildIndex" = 1
        | |   "IOPCIResourced" = Yes
        | |   "IODTPersist" = 0
        | |   "compatible" = <"pci8086,1578","pciclass,060400">
        | |   "ranges" = <0000008200000004000000000000008200000004000000000000100400000000000000c20000000000000000000000c2000000000000000000000000000000000000008100000000000000000000008100000000000000000000000000000000>
        | |   "IOPCIExpressLinkCapabilities" = 24206403
        | |   "IOServiceDEXTEntitlements" = (("com.apple.developer.driverkit.transport.pci","com.apple.developer.driverkit.transport.pci.bridge"))
        | |   "IOPCITunnelL1Enable" = No
        | |   "IOPCIConfigured" = Yes
        | |   "revision-id" = <00000000>
        | |   "IOPCIExpressLinkStatus" = 12354
        | |   "IOPCIExpressCapabilities" = 354
        | |   "pcidebug" = "2:1:0(3:3)"
        | |   "IOName" = "pci-bridge"
        | |   "#size-cells" = <02000000>
        | |   "reg" = <0008020000000000000000000000000000000000>
        | |   "IOPCIExpressSlotCapabilities" = 262144
        | | }
        | | 
        | +-o IOPP  <class IORegistryEntry:IOService:IOPCIBridge:IOPCI2PCIBridge, id 0x100002338, registered, matched, active, busy 0 (27 ms), retain 10>
        |   +-o pci10ee,7028@0  <class IORegistryEntry:IOService:IOPCIDevice, id 0x100002332, registered, matched, active, busy 0 (27 ms), retain 15>
        |     | {
        |     |   "assigned-addresses" = <10000382000000040000000000000004000000001800038200000008000000000000010000000000>
        |     |   "IOPCITunnelRootDeviceVendorID" = <43000000>
        |     |   "IOPCIDeviceMemoryMapSize" = 262144
        |     |   "class-code" = <00800500>
        |     |   "IOPCITunnelled" = Yes
        |     |   "IODeviceMemory" = (({"address"=25836912640,"length"=67108864}),({"address"=25904021504,"length"=65536}))
        |     |   "IOPowerManagement" = {"ChildrenPowerState"=2,"CurrentPowerState"=2,"CapabilityFlags"=258,"ChildProxyPowerState"=2,"MaxPowerState"=3}
        |     |   "subsystem-vendor-id" = <ee100000>
        |     |   "pci-aspm-default" = 1
        |     |   "iommu-parent" = "IODARTMapper is not serializable"
        |     |   "IOPCIDeviceMapperPageSize" = 16384
        |     |   "IOPCIHPType" = 48
        |     |   "vendor-id" = <ee100000>
        |     |   "name" = <"pci10ee,7028">
        |     |   "device-id" = <28700000>
        |     |   "IOChildIndex" = 1
        |     |   "IOPCIResourced" = Yes
        |     |   "compatible" = <"pci10ee,7","pci10ee,7028","pciclass,058000">
        |     |   "IODEXTMatchCount" = 1
        |     |   "IOPCIExpressLinkCapabilities" = 259202
        |     |   "IOServiceDEXTEntitlements" = (("com.apple.developer.driverkit.transport.pci"))
        |     |   "IOPCITunnelL1Enable" = No
        |     |   "subsystem-id" = <07000000>
        |     |   "revision-id" = <00000000>
        |     |   "IOPCIExpressLinkStatus" = 4162
        |     |   "IOPCIExpressCapabilities" = 2
        |     |   "pcidebug" = "3:0:0"
        |     |   "IOName" = "pci10ee,7028"
        |     |   "IOPCIDeviceMemoryMapBase" = 0
        |     |   "reg" = <000003000000000000000000000000000000000010000302000000000000000000000004000000001800030200000000000000000000010000000000>
        |     |   "IOPCITunnelRootDeviceModelID" = <61660000>
        |     | }
        |     | 
        |     +-o SmiPcie  <class IORegistryEntry:IOService:IOUserService, id 0x100002342, registered, matched, active, busy 0 (0 ms), retain 8>
        +-o pci-bridge@4  <class IORegistryEntry:IOService:IOPCIDevice, id 0x100002331, registered, matched, active, busy 0 (5 ms), retain 13>
          | {
          |   "IOPCIExpressLinkCapabilities" = 74538049
          |   "vendor-id" = <86800000>
          |   "class-code" = <00040600>
          |   "IOName" = "pci-bridge"
          |   "#size-cells" = <02000000>
          |   "IOPCITunnelled" = Yes
          |   "IOPCIExpressSlotCapabilities" = 2359392
          |   "IOPCIHPType" = 48
          |   "pcidebug" = "2:4:0(4:4)"
          |   "IOChildIndex" = 2
          |   "Thunderbolt Path" = "IOService:/AppleARMPE/arm-io@10F00000/AppleT811xIO/acio1@1F00000/AppleThunderboltHALType5/AppleThunderboltNHIType5/IOThunderboltControllerType5/IOThunderboltPort@7/IOThunderboltSwitchType5/IOThunderboltPort@1/IOThunderboltPort@1/IOThunderboltSwitchType3/IOThunderboltPort@7"
          |   "IOPCIExpressLinkStatus" = 4161
          |   "pci-aspm-default" = 3
          |   "IOPCIExpressCapabilities" = 354
          |   "IOServiceDEXTEntitlements" = (("com.apple.developer.driverkit.transport.pci","com.apple.developer.driverkit.transport.pci.bridge"))
          |   "IOPCIConfigured" = Yes
          |   "IOInterruptControllers" = ("ApplePCIECLegacyIntController-apciec1","APCIECMSIController-apciec1")
          |   "IODTPersist" = 0
          |   "Thunderbolt Entry ID" = 4294976281
          |   "IOPCIResourced" = Yes
          |   "IOPowerManagement" = {"ChildrenPowerState"=2,"CurrentPowerState"=2,"CapabilityFlags"=258,"ChildProxyPowerState"=2,"MaxPowerState"=3}
          |   "ranges" = <0000008200000000000000000000008200000000000000000000000000000000000000c20000000000000000000000c2000000000000000000000000000000000000008100000000000000000000008100000000000000000000000000000000>
          |   "name" = <"pci-bridge">
          |   "IOPCITunnelLinkChange" = Yes
          |   "compatible" = <"pci8086,1578","pciclass,060400">
          |   "IOReportLegendPublic" = Yes
          |   "IOPCIExpressSlotStatus" = 0
          |   "reg" = <0020020000000000000000000000000000000000>
          |   "IOReportLegend" = ({"IOReportGroupName"="Interrupt Statistics (by index)","IOReportChannels"=((5291294645182070784,4295098369,"               First Level Interrupt Handler Count"),(5291294645182070785,4295098369,"              Second Level Interrupt Handler Count"),(5291294645182070786,4295098369,"        First Level Interrupt Handler Time (MATUs)"),(5291294645182070787,4295098369,"   Second Level Interrupt Handler CPU Time (MATUs)"),(5291294645182070788,4295098369,"Second Level Interrupt Handler System Time (MATUs)")),"IOReportChannelInfo"={"IOReportChannelUnit"=0},"IOReportSubGroupName"="pci-bridge 1"})
          |   "device-id" = <78150000>
          |   "#address-cells" = <03000000>
          |   "revision-id" = <00000000>
          |   "IOInterruptSpecifiers" = (<0100000000000000>,<3204000000000100>)
          |   "IOPCIMSIMode" = Yes
          | }
          | 
          +-o IOPP  <class IORegistryEntry:IOService:IOPCIBridge:IOPCI2PCIBridge, id 0x10000233c, registered, matched, active, busy 0 (0 ms), retain 8>
```

[image]

- Info.plist

```
    <key>IOKitPersonalities</key>
    <dict>
        <key>SmiPcie</key>
        <dict>
            <key>CFBundleIdentifier</key>
            <string>$(PRODUCT_BUNDLE_IDENTIFIER)</string>
            <key>CFBundleIdentifierKernel</key>
            <string>com.apple.kpi.iokit</string>
            <key>IOClass</key>
            <string>IOUserService</string>
            <key>IOMatchCategory</key>
            <string>$(PRODUCT_BUNDLE_IDENTIFIER)</string>
            <key>IOProviderClass</key>
            <string>IOPCIDevice</string>
            <key>IOResourceMatch</key>
            <string>IOKit</string>
            <key>IOUserClass</key>
            <string>SmiPcie</string>
            <key>IOUserServerName</key>
            <string>$(PRODUCT_BUNDLE_IDENTIFIER)</string>
            <key>IOPCITunnelCompatible</key>
            <true/>
            <key>IOPCIPrimaryMatch</key>
            <string>0x000010EE&amp;0x0000FFFF</string>
            <key>UserClientProperties</key>
            <dict>
                <key>IOClass</key>
                <string>IOUserUserClient</string>
                <key>IOUserClass</key>
                <string>SmiPcieUc</string>
            </dict>
        </dict>
    </dict>
```

Comment: I don't see an obvious issue, could you post the `ioreg` output for the `IOPCIDevice` node you're trying to match, and IOKitPersonality dictionary/ies from your dext's Info.plist?

Comment: From the `ioreg` line `        |     +-o SmiPcie  <class IORegistryEntry:IOService:IOUserService, id 0x100002342, registered, matched, active, busy 0 (0 ms), retain 8>` it looks like your driver is running. Did you run that command when you had SIP disabled? If not, it seems like your problem might be something other than signing/entitlements?

Comment: Unrelated to entitlements, but [remove the `IOMatchCategory` property from your matching dictionary!](https://stackoverflow.com/a/75470680/48660). `IOResourceMatch` should also be removed, there's no need for it here. (I'll also point out that the driver will currently match *all* devices from vendor ID `0x10ee` regardless of device ID, but this might be intentional.)

Comment: Yes, my Driver is indeed running, because I set the dk=0x8001 suggested by you, so I want to know how to run dext correctly without using dk=0x8001.
SIP is turned off on all my macs because sometimes I still have to use kext.

Comment: Thanks for your reminder and suggestion！IOMatchCategory and IOResourceMatch have been removed.When applying for entitlements, I applied for all Device IDs of 0x10ee to facilitate subsequent device expansion.

Comment: So does it work without `dk=0x8001`? I don't see any obvious problems other than that log line, and I'm wondering if it's not relevant to your dext instance.

Comment: Entitlements for all devices of a vendor are fine (and usual, and need to match what Apple granted), but that doesn't mean you need to match all devices in the `Info.plist` too. (But without knowing your devices and driver functionality I can't say if it's a problem.)

Comment: "So does it work without dk=0x8001".
If dk=0x8001 dose not set, there will be an appeal problem.

Comment: 0x000010EE &amp; 0x0000FFFF

The purpose is to prevent the need to apply for a new number in the future, because the application is more troublesome

Comment: Are you encountering this error on a different Mac than the one with dk=0x8001? Because from your screenshots, it looks like you're using *development* code signing, not distribution (App Store or Developer ID), and you can only run development-signed binaries on the systems whose UUIDs are listed in the provisioning profile. Furthermore, disabling SIP causes various problems with dexts in my experience: the kernel seems to get confused between arm64 and arm64e binary types.

Comment: Note that the PCI transport entitlement doesn't need to be identical to IOKitPersonalities' matching dictionary, so your dext can match only the device needed.

Answer (score 1):

> Do I need to copy all the entitlements in the profile to the entitlements file?

No; Xcode will sometimes warn if the entitlements file doesn't contain one of the profile's entitlements, but this isn't in itself a problem, just warning you about a possible oversight.

> I want to know, what exactly is the problem that causes the error `provider entitlements check failed`

["Provider entitlements check failed"](https://github.com/apple-oss-distributions/xnu/blob/5c2921b07a2480ab43ec66f5b9e41cb872bc554f/iokit/Kernel/IOUserServer.cpp#L2618) means the dext does not satisfy the entitlements requirement posed by provider object's `IOServiceDEXTEntitlements` and [family-specific requirements](https://github.com/apple-oss-distributions/xnu/blob/5c2921b07a2480ab43ec66f5b9e41cb872bc554f/iokit/Kernel/IOUserServer.cpp#L2596).

For PCI, this means one of the dictionaries in the dext's `com.apple.developer.driverkit.transport.pci` entitlement must match the provider object. (Unless the device is a PCI bridge, in which case there are extra requirements.)

I can't see an obvious problem in what you've posted so far, but you haven't posted the match dictionary from your dext's Info.plist and the `ioreg` excerpt for the `IOPCIDevice` you're trying to match, perhaps you could update your answer with those?

Comment: Thank you for your answer, I have added relevant information here, please check if there is any problem.