# How to enable DriverKit-specific entitlements checks

Tags: entitlements, driverkit

Run the command below can disable DriverKit-specific entitlement checks in macOS. I learned this from [PCIE DriverKit cannot be loaded correctly due to entitlements issues](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76207058/pcie-driverkit-cannot-be-loaded-correctly-due-to-entitlements-issues).

sudo nvram boot-args="dk=0x8001"

How can I enable the DriverKit-specific entitlement checks again?
Thanks a lot in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you have no other `boot-args`, this should do it:

```
sudo nvram -d boot-args
```

Otherwise, just run `sudo nvram boot-args="<blah>"` without the `dk=0x8001` part.

Note that you do NOT want to use `dk=0x0` as this turns off DriverKit altogether!